# Does OS know program did malloc or free any memory location in memory block given from os?

Tags: c++, operating-system, window

Recently, I found some interesting code.

```
int main()
{
    int* a = new int;
    *a = 5;

    int* b = a;

    delete a;

    std::cout << *b << std::endl;
}
```

Even if this is "Undefined Behaviour", mostly It works well. It print '5'
And I learned this is because Program is accessing to already allocated memory block(maybe page??) from OS, It don't give any exception.

I have a question. Can OS know whether program allocate and deallocate memory in memory block??
Or Does program manage free memory list?( if program manage this, Why Doesn't it give any exception when access to freed location(b) )

**I wanna know how this things works in detail.**
And I wanna know when Program give back memory block to os.

I'm working on windows x64.

Comment: sometimes It give exception. Who give it?? OS? Program?

Comment: Functions that release dynamically allocated memory (e.g. `operator delete()`) are not required to immediately release it to the host system. Practically, they often do not, because *programmers* often repeatedly deallocate and later reallocate memory.  A round trip of releasing memory to the OS and requesting a similar block again is often more expensive computationally than for standard library functions to keep track and reuse previously "released" blocks without interacting with the OS. Different standard libraries, even versions of standard libraries, behave differently in this regard.

Comment: `A roung trip of releasing memory to the OS` means giving back page to os??

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour according to the standard - essentially, because your program assumes it can access dynamically allocated memory after it has been released.   An output of `5` is perfectly acceptable (e.g. because the memory has not *actually* been released to the OS).   And output of `42` is acceptable (e.g. because the OS simply retrieves a random value).   Reformatting your hard drive is acceptable (e.g. because your standard library overwrites some critical area of physical memory).   Such is the nature of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Standard c++ relies on a [memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) of an abstract machine, besides that the behaviour is implementation defined, so undefined

Comment: @MatG Implementation-defined and undefined are different things.

Comment: A "round trip of releasing memory to the OS" CAN mean giving a page of memory to the OS, and then (in response to a subsequent statement that dynamically allocates memory) requesting another page of memory.     Whether it actually means that depends on the implementation of the compiler, how the standard library is coded, how the OS manages memory, and a whole bunch of other things.

Comment: There is no one thing that makes it print `5`.    Just as there is no one thing that would cause your code to reformat your system drive.   But both are equally possible outcomes of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SungJinKang When you call `delete` that just tells the code to at some point release the memory back to the OS, you have no idea when (usually in the very near future however). So of course, if you print immediately after and that memory has not yet been released, you might print `5`. However, you may also print some other value (if that memory was used by for instance your call to `std::cout`). On the other hand, if the memory was already released to the OS you will be trying to access memory that is not yours, so the OS will raise an exception and your code will "crash".

Comment: @Evg yes, but they are brothers, better avoid them both

Comment: @Qubit Ok you mean exception is thrown by OS. Is it Right?? And Does `Memory Block` given from OS means `Page`??

Comment: @SungJinKang I won't say I know for sure exactly how this happens, I would assume you request the memory (by refering to the virtual memory address), there is then hardware that resolves the virtual address to an actual address and I would guess that is where the error is detected.  Then presumably this will signal the OS which will in turn raise the exception in your code (i.e. send SIGSEGV under Linux and something similar under Windows but with these dreaded handles). But like I said, I don't know for sure if that is exactly how this goes.

Comment: @Qubit Ok thanks for your reply. I think your saying `there is then hardware that resolves the virtual address to an actual address` about "MMU"

Comment: @SungJinKang As for the memory block, yes, typically you get a page or several pages, depending on how much memory you requested. So if you request anything up to 1 page in size you get 1 page, if you request something larger then obviously you get some number of pages that matches your request. But note that allocating memory doesn't actually give you the physical memory immeditely (i.e. you can allocate 1TB on your laptop if you want and so long as you don't write too much you'll be fine). So there's more depth to what is happening here as well.

Comment: @SungJinKang Yes but I didn't want to get into details.

Comment: @Qubit Ok thanks for your reply. Have a nice day!

Comment: This code crashes on my machine when executed, with a `heap-use-after-free` diagnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll answer from the C++ perspective:

> Does OS know program did malloc or free any memory location in memory block given from os?

> Can OS know whether program allocate and deallocate memory in memory block??

> And I wanna know when Program give back memory block to os.

These are not specified by the C++ language.

> mostly It works well.

No. A program with undefined behaviour doesn't "work well", even if it appears to do so.

> It print '5'

That's one possible behaviour. That's not guaranteed when the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> And I learned this is because Program is accessing to already allocated memory block(maybe page??) from OS, It don't give any exception.

It doesn't give any exception because it isn't guaranteed to do so because behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

Here I'll cover a bit from the OS perspective. Unfortunately, my Windows specific knowledge isn't deep, so this is more general than specific.

> Or Does program manage free memory list?

*Something* has to manage a data structure describing all of the allocatinos in practice. Whether that is the language implementation directly (compiler / runtime library) or the operating system varies across systems. I 've heard that on Windows this may also vary between debug and release builds.

> ( if program manage this, Why Doesn't it give any exception when access to freed location(b) )

Regardless of whether such list is managed by the language implementation (compiler / runtime library), or by the operating system, such checking isn't done because checking such list every time you access memory would be very expensive in terms of processor time. People who implemented the language or the operating system presumaby decided that slowing down every program by a significant factor was not worth the added safety.

Operating systems typically deal with virtual memory in "pages" which are big blocks. When a page that isn't mapped in memory is accessed, that is a point where the operating system typically checks whether the program should have access to it. If it doesn't, then the program is typically terminated for safety because it is deemed to behave erratically. These pages are a coarser division of memory than individual allocations.

> And I wanna know when Program give back memory block to os.

Again varies across implementations and cases. It is quite typical that memory isn't given back to operating system at all, and is instead used for later allocations. By "at all", I mean that the process retains the memory until it is terminated.